# Cypress text execution error after version update

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

While I was having cypress `5.0.0` version, all my test used to run fine.
Now that I've updated it to `6.5.0`, I am getting following error when I click on the test file.

````
**Title:** Error launching browser

**Message:** ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'https://xxx/__/#/tests/integration\demoTest.spec.js'

**Stack trace:**
```
Error: ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'https://xxx/__/#/tests/integration\demoTest.spec.js'
    at rejectAndCleanup (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:205:1493)
    at Object.stopLoadingListener (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:205:1868)
    at Object.emit (events.js:315:20)

```
````

I've also tried installing cypress `6.8.0`, but was have same issue, hence downgraded it, but still the error remains.

Comment: Maybe you need to clear out your node_modules folder? It might be that parts of the old version haven’t been removed from there.

Comment: Even though I tried installing `cypress` in a completely new and empty directory, it's still giving me same error

Comment: Maybe you need to clean the cache for the package manager you’re using. You can run npm cache clean --force to do this.

Comment: No, it's not working even after clearing the cache