# "Error Launching Browser" When Running Electron from Cypress

Tags: electron, cypress

I am getting a the following error while trying to launch electron from Cypress:

```
Error: ERR_FAILED (-2) loading 'http://localhost:4200/__/#/tests/integration/features/AssetDownload/assetDownload.feature'
    at rejectAndCleanup (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:217:1457)
    at Object.stopLoadingListener (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:217:1832)
    at Object.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

I have already tried the suggestions listed in this SO post:
[Cypress text execution error after version update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66733806/cypress-text-execution-error-after-version-update/67695562#67695562)

I have electron 89 and Cypress 7.2.0. I am able to launch Firefox.

EDIT #1:
I am already running as administrator.

I also tried printing debug info:
set DEBUG=cypress:*
npx cypress run

stderr log captured:
cypress:server:browsers:electron debugger: received response to Browser.getVersion: { jsVersion: '8.8.278', product: 'Chrome/89.0.4328.0', protocolVersion: '1.3', revision: '@1b62e1740a6ff70baeff81b5e0133255a10ee584', userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Cypress/7.2.0 Chrome/89.0.4328.0 Electron/12.0.0-beta.14 Safari/537.36' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: 'ffmpeg version N-92722-gf22fcd4483 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers' } +153ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181201' } +1ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libavutil      56. 24.101 / 56. 24.101' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libavcodec     58. 42.102 / 58. 42.102' } +1ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libavformat    58. 24.101 / 58. 24.101' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libavfilter     7. 46.101 /  7. 46.101' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100' } +0ms
cypress:server:video capture stderr log { message: '  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100' } +0ms

Also the standard error message:
We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed.

This is the equivalent to seeing the 'sad face' when Chrome dies.

This can happen for a number of different reasons:

- You wrote an endless loop and you must fix your own code
- There is a memory leak in Cypress (unlikely but possible)
- You are running Docker (there is an easy fix for this: see link below)
- You are running lots of tests on a memory intense application
- You are running in a memory starved VM environment
- There are problems with your GPU / GPU drivers
- There are browser bugs in Chromium

I doubt it's any of the above reasons.

Comment: Hi, Could you try to run as an administrator user and let me know how it behaves. It may be a policy issue. Refer more: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Cypress-detected-policy-settings-on-your-computer-that-may-cause-issues

Comment: Please see my EDIT #1 above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did you try with a non-administrator user then?

Comment: Thanks running with non-administrator eliminated the error.  Can you please write up an answer explaining why?  I am happy to review and potentially mark and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because of policy settings on your computer that may cause issues, need to disable proxy policies to handle with admin access or else run a script with a non-admin user. [Refer more](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages#Cypress-detected-policy-settings-on-your-computer-that-may-cause-issues)